# How to use MemoryRouter and BrowserRouter in the same time at react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to have url changings for certain routes and for other routes have a memory based routing. 
Is there a smooth way to combine MemoryRouter with BrowserRouter?